# Count same name column from different sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables `scan_1`, `scan_2`, `scan_3`. Here is structure of SQL schema:

```
scan_1:                 scan_2:                   scan_3:
P_no work               P_no work                 P_no work
1    YES                1    YES                  1    NO
2    NO                 2    NO                   2    NO
3    YES                3    YES                  3    NO
```

I want to count `P_no` where `work ='YES'`. But if yes occurred in 2 position LIKE for `P_no = 1` which having YES in `scan_1` and `scan_2` it must be count as 1.

my query is :

```
SELECT count(`P_no`) AS `ab1` FROM 
`scan_1`,`scan_2`,`scan_3` WHERE 
((`scan_1`.`work`= 'YES') OR 
(`scan_2`.`work`= 'YES') OR 
(`scan_3`.`work`= 'YES'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you as far I understood. Using union for eliminating duplicates.

```
    select count(*) AS `ab1` FROM
    (
    select `P_no`,`work` from `scan_1` s1 where `work`= 'YES' 
     union
    select `P_no`,`work` from `scan_2` s2 where `work`= 'YES'
     union
     select `P_no`,`work` from `scan_3` s3 where `work`= 'YES' 
    ) as final
```

Comment: Error : check the manual for the right syntax to use near 'as one
union

Comment: Sorry MySql is not current installed on my pc. Can you check the edit again?

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count 
FROM
    (
        SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_1 WHERE work = 'YES'
        UNION
        SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_2 WHERE work = 'YES'
        UNION
        SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_3 WHERE work = 'YES'
    ) AS total
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired result using **UNION** like below :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ab1
FROM (
    SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_1 WHERE work='YES'
    UNION
    SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_2 WHERE work='YES'
    UNION
    SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_3 WHERE work='YES'
) as T
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d660e/1)

Notice the three queries which is merged using **UNION.** It merges the result and excludes the duplicate records from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P_No) AS ab1
FROM (
    SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_1
    UNION
    SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_2
    UNION
    SELECT P_no, work FROM scan_3
) T
WHERE T.Work='YES'
```

Hope this helps you.